# How to implicitly cast an array type to a tuple type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Now, `args` is a rest parameter of a tuple type. How to make this constructor also accept arrays, which, when cast to tuple type, will result in a type that is specified in a said constructor?

Can it be done without manual assertion on construction, e.g.:

```js
const args = [3, 5];

let vector = new Vector(...args as [number, number]);
```

or

```js
const args: [number, number] = [3, 5];

let vector = new Vector(...args);
```

---

```js
class Vector {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(...args: [] | [number] | [number, number]) {
        switch(args.length) {
            case 0:
                this.x = 0;
                this.y = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                this.x = this.y = args[0];
                break;
            case 2:
                this.x = args[0];
                this.y = args[1];
                break;
        }
    }
}

const args = [3, 5];

let vector = new Vector(...args);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmwAuB7ATtA3gKGn6AHgFzQB2ArgLYBG8aA3LvgJ4kU12NN7AqkRI05ZOgAUAOklg0AcwgkA2gF1oAH2gL2tNCvWaq2gDRkDdJQEos3fHggB3AJZJgAC1HS54kPFIykLyxwbYPxgSHhoAAYiaxCQ-wcIcQJoAF4oxjis6ASk5jSM2Oy8ajR4MABrTOLoMIgIgEYYmuDc5IK2-PSPCAVIpWqWkrLKwey6iIAmZqG8NpTu2V7+sZbOgp6FBoGi4tLyqt3oAF9rU9PsXn4kaB6ChQBmYwBWHexvG4A3RFQMdNJ4HY4D8xJJxD1zPQgA)

**EDIT**: Considering @philipp-fritsche answer, what if I would add these overloads?

```js
class Vector {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor();
    constructor(xy: number);
    constructor(x: number, y: number);
    constructor(arg1?: number, arg2?: number) {
        if(arg1 === undefined) {
            this.x = this.y = 0;
        } else if (arg2 == undefined) {
            this.x = this.y = arg1;
        } else {
            this.x = arg1;
            this.y = arg2;
        }
    }
}

const args = [1, 2];

let vector = new Vector(...args);
```

Comment: Sounds like you want `const args = [3, 5] as const;`.

Comment: @kaya3 is there a way to not do anything outside the `Vector` class?

Comment: Uh, well `args` has type `number[]` so the only way to edit the `Vector` class to make this type-check would be for your constructor to accept `number[]`.

Comment: Here you can find overloadings https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmwAuB7ATtA3gKGn6AHgFzQB2ArgLYBG8aA3LvgJ4kU12NN7AqkRI05ZOgAUASkb5ovfoOGo0oggH42VWmkncZfAUJFLV6jmgA00ZmrIa62nbP0KxYNAHMAjNfaaLrtwBM3rZaWDrSAJYAZtCi-h7QALzJ0OSkACbwURGk8OniYdJF+EgAFhEQAHQESdBlFZXMtQAMUsXQAL7Q8CAQ8NDRsf4BSYmpGVk5eQU47UX1VTVjC4218W3FXT19hXMl5Ytr7h4beytNY8On0h06t7fYjkjQ-jBjANoeFgEAulwg8GeADdEIparkAO5wUFiSpw16SIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no benefit here in defining the parameters per rest.

```
class Vector {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x?: number, y?: number) {
        this.x = x ?? 0
        this.y = y ?? x ?? 0
    }
}

const args = [3, 5];

let vector = new Vector(...args);
```

This works because the type infered for args is `number[]`. And the elements `0` and `1` of `number[]` are `number | undefined` which matches the parameters for `Vector`.

If you specify `...args: [] | [number] | [number, number]`, `0`, `1` or `2` arguments are allowed. But `number[]` can have `>=0` elements. So this violates your explicit type.

Answer (score 0):

Considering @philipp-fritsche answer and @captain-yossarian comment, here is the final version, with the little addition.

```js
class Vector {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor();
    constructor(xy?: number);
    constructor(x?: number, y?: number);
    constructor(xy?: Vector);

    constructor(arg1?: number | Vector, arg2?: number) {
        if (arg1 === undefined) {
            this.x = this.y = 0;
        } else if (arg1 instanceof Vector) {
            this.x = arg1.x;
            this.y = arg1.y;
        } else if (arg2 == undefined) {
            this.x = this.y = arg1;
        } else {
            this.x = arg1;
            this.y = arg2;
        }
    }
}

const args = [1, 2];

let vector = new Vector(...args);

console.log(vector);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqCmwAuB7ATtA3gKGn6AHgFzQB2ArgLYBG8aA3LvgJ4kU12NN7AqkRI05ZOgAUASkb5ovfoOGo0ogswD8bKrTSTuMvgKEilBdWU10ANNDUaO2qflkGFYlaYRGdup-KOiwaADmAIym7FrQAD5wiIpWAYEATGHm2li60gCWAGbQ-kHB0AC8JdDkpAAm8NmZpPAV4unSzfhIABaZEAB0BMXQ7Z1dzH0ADA4tAL7Q8CAQ8NA5eQmFtQJgpMDwKLkeio04LS0D3b1F0Ms944d4x0N9F8xX0lMzcwu5+UnFZ+VVNXUNJrXVodE59W7DM7LJ74F6zeYHYE3UE9e4FGFHFGQ85BRIY6ATXSEwnYHw4wIwM4AbWCVkSAF0uCB4EhoAA3WLoPp1ADuMT8XUFCQgXicKGZXRAKECog5nnoQA)